# jquery sum from different divs with same classes

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="sub_total">34,814.64</div>
<div class="sub_total">39,800.64</div>
<div class="sub_total">14,004.04</div>
```

I want to sum by class
I tried by this way

```
var sum = 0;

$('.sub_total_w_tax').each(function(){
     sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
});
```

but the result is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the commas before adding.

```
var sum = 0;

$('.sub_total').each(function(){

sum += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/,/g , ""));

});
alert(sum);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/stb0sd71/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `,` from the string, otherwise while it parsing `34,814.64` will get as `34`

```js
var sum = 0;

$('.sub_total').text(function(i, v) {
  sum += parseFloat(v.replace(',', ''));
});

$('#result').text('Result : ' + sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub_total">34,814.64</div>
<div class="sub_total">39,800.64</div>
<div class="sub_total">14,004.04</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```